# Update record with image using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm having problems updating a record with an image. I don't know what I need to do. My image is stored in a public folder called 'img/products'.

I use this method in my controller to store the 'product'

```html
$productImage = $request->file('image');
        $productImageName = rand() . '.' . $productImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $productImage->move(public_path('img/products'), $productImageName);

        $products = Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price_neto' => $request->price_neto,
            'iva' => $request->iva,
            'price_total' => $request->price_total,
            'image' => $productImageName,
        ]);
```

**ProductController.php**

In the controller is where I have more doubts if my code is right or wrong.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price_neto' => 'required',
            'iva' => 'required',
            'price_total' => 'required',
            'image' => '',
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $products = Product::find($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $path = public_path("img/products/" . $products->image);

            if(File::exists($path)) {

                File::delete($path);

                $productImage = $request->file('image');
                $productImageName = rand() . '.' . $productImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $productImage->move(public_path('img/products'), $productImageName);

                $products->image = $productImageName;
            }
        }

        $products->name = $request->name;
        $products->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $products->description = $request->description;
        $products->price_neto = $request->price_neto;
        $products->iva = $request->iva;
        $products->price_total = $request->price_total;

        $products->save();

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ]);
    }
```

***Product.js***

```js
$("#btn-edit").click(function() {

        var form = new FormData($("#frmEditProduct")[0]);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/product/' + $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),
            data: form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
                $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
                $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                    $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
                $("#edit-error-bag").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

***Route***

```js
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function () {
        Route::get('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@show',
            'as'   => 'product.show',
        ]);

        Route::post('/', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@store',
            'as'   => 'product.store',
        ]);

        Route::put('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@update',
            'as'   => 'product.update',
        ]);

        Route::delete('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@destroy',
            'as'   => 'product.destroy',
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: what's the actual error you're experiencing? does the image path not update?

Comment: We can't understand what's your problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do the registry update. I don't know, if I have something wrong with my controller or my js file @nmfzone

Comment: @DanielT. What is `registry update`? Sorry, but I'm not understand. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid using Laravels' File storage system? Completely fine if you do, I just want to make sure you're aware that it exists https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Comment: Because in this way I did the insert and delete. No other reason. @AlecJoy

Comment: With those modifications I made, the error say `All fields are required` although when I click on the edit button it throws `{{"error": false, "products": {"id": 40, "name": "test", "category_id": 1, "description": "test" , "price_neto": "123456.00", "VAT": "16049.28", "price_total": "139505.00", "image": "117354918.jpg", "created_at": "2019-10-23 21:52:45 "," updated_at ":" 2019-10-23 21:52:45 "}}` all fields are good @maximus1127

Comment: In this way it is possible to modify the registry with the image? and how should I do it? @nmfzone